# How to create subnets with even distribution of IP addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

There is a lot of information about subnetting on the internet, but I am looking for a formula or algorithm to help me set up a VPC on AWS.

The network has a block of `10.0.0.0/16` and I want to create 6 subnets, all with the same number of available IPs.

How can I figure out the CIDR notation for each subnet?

Comment: There is a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that addresses that specifically.

Comment: Cheers, @RonMaupin -- Thanks

Comment: Was that useful? I strove to explain just about everything for IPv4 addressing and subnetting, and it should be easy to adapt that to most programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a tool that makes this problem really easy: http://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html